# Dataset from online forum

Tags: data-request, nlp, research

Recently I started to do some researchs on QA data aiming to rank quality answers from determined questions, for this I used the avaliables Yahoo! and StackExchange datasets.

Now, I would like to expand the research for identify potential answers to the thread starter along all posts on that thread. For this, I searched for some online forum dataset, possibly annotated (like the Ancestry.com, unavailable now), because on online forum a reply on a thread not always means that is a direct answer to the thread starter. But I couldn't find any dataset like this.

Do you guys know about some avaliable dataset that could help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The StackExchange sites themselves seem your best bet!
(*Note: Question was edited after this to exclude StackExchange as well*)

Read [Introducing Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/06/13/introducing-stack-exchange-data-explorer/), which is about [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/), where you can run queries, and about the [dumps of all the public data in the current Stack Exchange network](https://stackoverflow.blog/tags/cc-wiki-dump/).

This means you can either access the data through SEDE or download it all and play with it, with proper attribution ([Creative Commons Attribution – Share Alike](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)) of course.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I also realize that the StackExchange sites could help and I have done some tests with good results, but unfortunately this dataset has the same problem of Yahoo!, I can only rank the quality and can't identify what could or not be a candidate answer, because all of them are, almost always, direct candidate answers to the inicial question, different of the posts along a forum thread =(